# ajax response error not working as expected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My success/error handling is not working as expected.  In this example my php runs as intended, however, the intent of the processing failed.  Let's say I was looking up a username in the database... if I found the username I would return `$ajax_result['success'] = 'success';`, but if I did not find the username I would return nothing.  The success call works fine, but the error call is not firing.

The error in firebug I am getting is `TypeError: response is null` and therefore the error alert I have set does not fire.

What is the best way to solve this without actually returning `$ajax_result['success'] = 'whatever';`

example return from php would be something like this when processing went as expected:

```
$ajax_result['success'] = 'success'; // add success info
echo json_encode($ajax_result); // return result array to ajax
```

for 'errors' I am simply returning :

```
echo json_encode($ajax_result); // which is null in this case
```

the ajax:

```
var showInfo = function() {
    $('#show-user').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/spc_admin/process/p_delete_user_show.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.success == 'success') {            
                alert('success');              
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not `json_encode` a null value, easiest and cleanest way to make this work would probably be to make `success` a bool and set it to either `true` or `false` depending on if it succeeded or not (This is ususaly what most user expects a 'success' or 'result' parameter in response to be, not a string).

```
//PHP:
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // To let the client know that its json-data.
$ajax_result['success'] = $wasSuccessfull; // true or false
die(json_encode($ajax_result)); // Exit the script with the json response.


//JavaScript:
if (response.success) {            
  alert('success');              
} else {
  alert('error');
}
```

Comment: Nothing - same `TypeError: response is null`

Comment: If you try access the php script through the browser, do you get the correct response? And do you return it with header content-type: application/json?

Comment: the success call works perfectly fine... it is only when `$ajax_result['success'] = 'success';` is not set... so I am returning a null array which should trigger the error cal... or so I thought.

Comment: Does the php script echo out `TypeError: response is null` or is it the javascript.

Comment: its the js file and points to `if (response.success == 'success') {`

Comment: When you return `json_encode(null);` the response will just be 'null', not any valid json, so the `response` object will only be null. You wont be able to check the `success` parameter, cause the object is null. You will have to echo some valid json from the php script for it to exist.

Comment: Makes sense... just assumed the other way I guess.  This being said, I think I will just set `$ajax_result['success'] = 'failed';` or something at the beginning of the php processing then.  Thanks.

Comment: Great. I would tho still recommend using boolean values. Its what most people would expect it to be and its harder to make any errors with it (for example misspells when checking response, hehe).

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
  if (!response.success) {            
        alert('error');              
  } 
  else 
  {
        alert('success');
  }
```

Comment: seems your client side cannot communicate with the server, please check the urls if it corrects.